# My page is shown as archive in my site

Tags: archives, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I've made a real estate website with Wordpress and I'm facing some issues. People register on the website as users, agents and agencies. On the agencies page where all registered agencies show it shows as archive and the design is changed a little bit and I don't know how to change it back to what it was. This is the page I'm talking about:
https://www.imobil.al/agjensi/

This is how it was and how it should look: http://test.imobil.al/index.php/agjensi/
I'm using Yoast SEO and when I deactivate the plugin the "archive" in the title goes away but the design does not change. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminology of WordPress, an "archive" is where posts of a certain type are listed.  The archive is simply the place to view all of your posts of a certain type, such as your agency post type.

From looking at the class names added to the  element of the two pages you linked, I can see two different templates are in-use.

An abbreviated copy of the `body` element from your intended layout:
`<body class="page-template page-template-page-agencies page-template-page-agencies-php page page-id-1468 ... " data-elementor-device-mode="desktop">`

This shows that your theme has a template named `page-agencies.php` that creates the look/layout that you had and want to restore.

Somehow in your theme or plugin settings that template is no-longer being used.  Instead, the broken layout you have now is (probably) using the theme's default `archive.php` template.  This might be due to changes in your Yoast plugin settings but I am not familiar enough with the plugin to confirm.